# Export a large image from Google earth engine platform

Tags: google-earth-engine

```js
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('users/vguyir/NewBegoro');
Map.addLayer(aoi)

var Begoro = aoi.filter(ee.Filter.eq('FID', 0));
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
         .filterBounds(geometry)
         .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
         .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
        ;
//Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3','B2'], min:0 ,max: 3000}, 'L1');

var Sort = image.toList(20)
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(Sort.get(1)), {band: ['B1', 'B2','B3'], min:0, max: 0.3},'Landsat 1')

//Map.addLayer(geometry, {}, 'Geometry');

var clip = ee.Image(Sort.get(1)).clip(table2);
Map.addLayer(clip, {band: ['B1', 'B2','B3'], min:0, max:3000}, 'clip');

var image2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
         .filterBounds(geometry2)
         .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
         .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
        ;
//Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3','B2'], min:0 ,max: 3000}, 'L1');

var Sort2 = image2.toList(20)
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(Sort2.get(1)), {band: ['B1', 'B2','B3'], min:0, max: 0.3},'Landsat 1')

var clip = ee.Image(Sort2.get(3)).clip(table2);
Map.addLayer(clip, {band: ['B1', 'B2','B3'], min:0, max:3000}, 'clip');

var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image(Sort.get(1)),ee.Image(Sort2.get(1))]).mosaic();
Map.addLayer(mosaic, {bands: ['B4','B3', 'B2'], min:0 ,max:3000}, 'mosaic');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mosaic.clip(aoi).select('B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2'),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 10,
  region: mosaic.clip(aoi),
  folder : 'Tank',
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  crs : 'EPSG:32630'
});
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Export too large: specified 37842166724310 pixels (max:
>   3784216672400). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export
>   a large area

Comment: the solution seems to be "Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area"

Comment: Do you really want to export an image with 37,842,166,724,310 pixels into your drive account?  `maxPixels` is there to force you to consider that.  Also, you should be using `clipToCollection()` in this context.

Answer (score 8):

In the function:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mosaic.clip(aoi).select('B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2'),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 10,
  region: mosaic.clip(aoi),
  folder : 'Tank',
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  crs : 'EPSG:32630'
});
```

'maxPixels' is the largest size dataset that you are able to export (in pixels). Your image is 10 pixels larger than this. If you set maxPixels to 37842166724310 or greater then it will export.

However, be warned, that is a lot of pixels to export into your drive, especially if it is a multi-band image

Answer (score 0):

Set the max pixels value: 1e13

Answer (score -3):

you should add 10 more pixel and you are good to go

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please take the [Tour] to get accustomed i.a. with how to write a *good* answer; the core of this community being the scientific expertise of the presented solutions to specific problems, an answer can, most of all, not be a one-liner! Use the [edit] function to add *way* more detail as to why you believe your proposition might help in solving the issue.

Comment: Indeed, 34057950051910 more pixels to `maxPixels` argument... You should check your maths