# Error while exporting from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, export, classification

I run an unsupervised classification with Google Earth Engine using this code:

```
    // UNSUPERVISED classification of Conifers//

var input = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");

var geometry = 
    /* color: #98ff00 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[7.582719257752308, 46.02568420992065],
          [7.582719257752308, 44.97372238809936],
          [9.228269435087903, 44.97372238809936],
          [9.228269435087903, 46.02568420992065]]], null, false);
          
  
input = input.filterBounds(geometry);
print(input);

input = input.filterDate('2020-08-06','2020-08-08');
print(input);
  
input = input.sort('CLOUD_COVER');

input = input.mosaic();
print(input);
  
input = input.clip(geometry);
print(input);

Map.centerObject(geometry,9);  
  
Map.addLayer(input,{min:-157.33,max:1421.15,bands:['B4','B3','B2']}, 'input image');
  
var training = input.sample({
  region: geometry,
  scale: 10,
  numPixels: 5000
});

var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(15).train(training);

var result =  input.cluster(clusterer);

Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'Unsupervised Classified Image');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: result,
  description: 'Unsupervised Classified Image',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry
});
```

When I run the code with **10m scale** in the training part and choose 10m also while exporting, it never finished the export to drive and I got this error:

Error: Export too large: specified 214533809 pixels (max: 100000000). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area.

However, when I set the scale in code and while exporting to 20m, it got exported in 8 minutes.
I need the result in 10m resolution so how can I change the code so it exports a 10m resolution? This is my first attempt in GEE and I am not familiar with how the scale and numPixel have to change.
Please let me know if I can modify any other part of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export a large image from Google earth engine platform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267523/export-a-large-image-from-google-earth-engine-platform)

Comment: Thanks @HMSP, I read this question and applied teh answer given respect to my number of pixels, but it still does not export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export.image.toDrive()` defaults to `maxPixels = 1E8`, and you're trying to export more than that. So try increasing `maxPixels`:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: result,
  description: 'Unsupervised Classified Image',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 1E10
});
```

Comment: Thanks @hooge048, I specified maxPixels: 1E10, but I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (28:3) and the line in code is red.

Comment: There's probably a incorrect character on line 28, position 3.