# Create a mosaic in Google Earth Engine in natural colors RGB (4,3,2 channel Sentinel -2) in GeoTIFF format

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

I need to continue working with a mosaic in ArcMap, I wanted to optimize my work so as not to download for monitoring many pictures. I am attaching my code, I tried to make a mosaic, but I can not export.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
  .filterDate('2021-08-01' ,'2021-08-30') 
  .filterBounds(polygon) ;
  
  print(collection) ;
  
   //Let's centre the map view over our ROI
Map.centerObject(polygon, 5);
var medianpixels = collection.median(); // This finds the median value of all the pixels which meet the criteria. 
var medianpixelsclipped = medianpixels.clip(polygon).divide(10000);
// Now visualise the mosaic as a natural colour image. 
Map.addLayer(medianpixelsclipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 1, gamma: 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export your RGB mosaic to Google Drive by using the following code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: medianpixelsclipped.select(['B4','B3','B2']),
  description: 'myMosaic',
  scale: 10,
  region: polygon,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326' // or the one you prefer
});
```

Comment: it shows error -  Error: Export too large: specified 8291273144 pixels (max: 100000000). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area. (Error code: 3)

Comment: Have a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267523/export-a-large-image-from-google-earth-engine-platform

Answer (score 0):

add
maxPixels: 1e13
To the export function as given below:

`Export.image.toDrive({  image:medianpixelsclipped.select(['B4','B3','B2']),  description: 'myMosaic',  scale: 10,  region: polygon, maxPixels: 1e13, crs: 'EPSG:4326' // or the one you prefer });`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanx!!!!!!!))))))))